# Python SQLite3 query concatenating two values

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database (student.db) that contains one table (Students).
Each row in students contains (ID, FName, LName).
There is an existing row (0, John, Doe).
I want to be able to enter a variable as a full name, find that name in the database, and delete that row.
Here's what I came up with... but it doesn't seem to work:

```
import sqlite3    

conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
c = conn.cursor()

selection = "John Doe"

c.execute('DELETE FROM Students WHERE (FName + " " + LName =?', (selection,))
```

I don't get an error message. I'm guessing that's because it simply doesn't find any entries that match the WHERE clause.

**Is there a way to properly write a WHERE clause that incorporates multiple values from the row of interest?**

I am very new to this, so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I'm trying to make a Kivy app that creates a ListView of student names. Then you can select a student from the list and click "Delete" to remove that student from the ListView dictionary and from the database.

Comment: Well, the super-simple approach here would just be to split `John Doe` in two, and use `AND` in your query. That would get you past the first hurdle, but I think it might cause problems later on because names are notoriously difficult to work with (some people have one name, some might have 5, etc). What is the real source of `"John Doe" in your example?

Comment: do you want the selection to be spliited to `FName: Joe` and `LName: Doe` and then use it in your query?

Comment: The only reason I don't want to do split is because you could have names like "Mary Ann" for a first name... which could cause problems.
The name "John Doe" comes from a python dictionary. The dictionary is currently set up as a list of full names. I'm sure the dictionary could be modified, but I was trying to follow a embellish upon a tutorial I found for Kivy
https://youtu.be/dxXsZKmD3Kk?list=PLGLfVvz_LVvTn3cK5e6LjhgGiSeVlIRwt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concatenation most SQL implementations use '||' operator. See [SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops).

`c.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE (FName || ' ' || LName = ?", (selection,))`

Answer (score 0):

[Working with names is difficult](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) but I think I'm over-thinking your question. Assuming that you just want to query two fields, you can split the name into a `first_name` and a `last_name`, and delete from the DB where that combination is satisfied.

```
selection = "John Doe"
first_name, last_name = selection.split()

query = """
        DELETE FROM Students 
        WHERE FName = ? AND LName = ?
        """

c.execute(query, (first_name, last_name))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: The only reason I don't want to use selection.split() is because you could have names like "Mary Ann Robinson" where Mary Ann is the "first name"

Comment: In which case, how do you expect the query to handle that case?

Comment: @JED It's possible that you can store this data more easily. I should have waited for an answer to my comment. If the source of the data is the database itself (then reported on the screen) then this isn't an issue.

Comment: I think that I need to come to terms with the fact that I am completely overthinking this tutorial video lol. But yes, if this were being done for a real life application, then the way that the full name of interest is being created should be different.